# How to find the mean of each group and barplot?

Tags: r, bar-chart, mean

I have an .csv file containing a table. I need to work with two columns out of the table, `Year` and `TV`.

[image]

I need to find the mean for each year (fresh, soph, jun, sen) then display it using `barplot`. I tried to use `tapply`/`mean`/`barplot` together but I just cant figure it out. So far I separated the data into sections based on the year and I know how to get `mean()`, but I just cant combine them all into one `barplot`. Is there a way to do this all in one code block using `tapply`?